# how to edit opencart php codes of admin area?

Tags: opencart

i want to edit and change the admin->catalog->product->edit->option attributes name i.e. price, point and weight to something else. I do it in admin/view/template/product-form.tpl but it does not reflect the change please help.

i change this:

```
 <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_subtract; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-right"><?php echo $entry_price; ?></td>
```

to this

```
<td class="text-left"><?php echo "something"; ?></td>
                          <td class="text-right"><?php echo "something"; ?></td>
```

Comment: Add some code snippet, what you tried?

Comment: You want to change texts?

Comment: yes text and also some programming in product-form.tpl basically i want to know how to edit  product-form.tpl as the change is not reflecting

Comment: Unrelated, but I just read this about OpenCart: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/5hezip/is_opencart_as_bad_as_it_seems/